# How to transfer constructor parameters to AppDomain.CreateInstanceXXX?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, appdomain, remoting

My class has no default parameterless constructor. It has such a constructor instead:

```
public Section(string fileName) {...}
```

I am to create an instance of my class inside of some `AppDomain`. If my class had a default constructor, then I would do it like this:

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ACAD-0001:409");

ISection section = (ISection)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    typeof(Section).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Section).FullName);
```

But there is no default constructor. How can I transfer the parameters of my constructor?

I expected it to work something like this:

```
string cuiFile = "...";
ISection section = (ISection)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    typeof(Section).Assembly.FullName, 
    typeof(Section).FullName, 
    new object[] { cuiFile });
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd414842(v=vs.110).aspx - note that there are TWO object[] - one is ARGS you wanted, the other is attributes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd414842(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public object CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    string assemblyName,
    string typeName,
    bool ignoreCase,
    BindingFlags bindingAttr,
    Binder binder,
    object[] args,            // <-- args go here
    CultureInfo culture,
    object[] activationAttributes
)
```